# How to populate listView with value coming from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to populate my list view every time a value is changed with the changed value

The code for ValueEventListener is as

```
ValueEventListener changeListener3 = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String carNumber = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            listPopulate(carNumber);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
```

And the function to populate the value is

```
public void listPopulate(String carNumber)
    {

        List<String> parkings = new ArrayList<>();

        parkings.add(carNumber);

        final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,parkings);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

But when I run it the value is updated in listView but it simply replace the current value I want to keep the last value along with new update data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement, `List<String> parkings = new ArrayList<>();` is creating a new empty list every time listPopulate is called. You need to move `List<String> parkings = new ArrayList<>();` outside of the listPopulate method in order to preserve the ArrayList you're creating.

example

```
public List<String> parking;

public void onCreate(xxxxxxxxxxxx){
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

    parking = new ArrayList<>();

}


public void listPopulate(xxxx){
    xxxxxxx
    xxxxxxx
    xxxxxx

}
```

If you want to preserve the list after closing the app, you'll need to cache the list locally on the device.